# Exporting Netezza query into SAS format

Tags: sas, netezza

Is there a way to save the results from a Netezza SQL query into a sas7bdat format?

I am currently exporting as a CSV, importing into SAS, and then exporting as a sas file.  I am trying to cut out the middle step in this process.

Comment: You can use a database connector and run `proc sql` to save the data as a SAS data set.

Comment: Yeah, I know about this sort of option.  I guess my goal is to run this process without opening SAS at all.

Comment: Can Netezza connect to other DBMSs using OLEDB or ODBC?

Comment: SAS is not a DBMS per se so the answer is no - Can you run command line scripts from Netezza? you can have a sas script launched from within netezza that will read your CSV into SAS data set. Not sure what you mean by ***'nd then exporting as a sas file'*** once read-in the CSV is already a sas file or sas data set.